# Image Folder to avi video not loading in correct order

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, avi

```
import cv2
import os

video = cv2.VideoCapture("Trolling_Vegans.mp4")
fps = video.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS)

image_folder = 'folder'
video_name = 'video.avi'

images = [img for img in os.listdir(image_folder) if img.endswith(".png")]
frame = cv2.imread(os.path.join(image_folder, images[0]))
height, width, layers = frame.shape

video = cv2.VideoWriter(video_name, 0, fps, (width,height))

for image in images:
    video.write(cv2.imread(os.path.join(image_folder, image)))

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
video.release()
```

I am trying to create an video from a folder of images, which are ordered sequentially e.g frame1.png, frame2.png etc.

The problem is when the video is made the images are essentially randomised. 
Why is this happening?
What is the fix?

Comment: typically images are fetched from a folder in alphabetic order. That means image10 is next to image1. So if you want them to load numerically and alphabetically, you need to add leading zeros to the numbers.

Comment: I added in trailing zeros and removed the text, so just 001.png etc. still the same, how to i load numerically?

Comment: That should work if you do not have any spaces and those are zeros and not ohs.

Comment: Did you sort images list after loading them